# Make a python server receive files sent using curl

Tags: python, curl, server, file-transfer

I want to make a python script that would run a server which I can then send a request to from another pc using curl to send a file. So I would send a file from a pc to the server using curl and then server would save that file.

I tried googling but couldn't seem to find anything like that, but I found that pycurl might be useful. If anyone could show me the direction towards my goal I would appreciate it.

Comment: File upload to an endpoint can get tricky. My naive kneejerk reaction would be to looking into flask since `curl` suggests the server would be running a web server and flask feels like a good fit. [some documentation here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/patterns/fileuploads/) on how to allow a file upload with that module. Alternatively [fastapi may offer a similar approach](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/).

Comment: It is actually very easy.  Is the server yours?  So both the apps (client and server) going to be written by you.  What type of file?  JSON?  TEXT?  IMAGE?

Answer (score 0):

Sending files is typically just a `POST` with data. You can make a webserver using something such as flask, and make an endpoint that receives post data, then saves it as a file.
On the server, you don't need curl at all, just an HTTP server that accepts requests.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I search for tutorial on this but I can only see people that actually have a website on which they click a button to select a file and upload it and I don't see the actual request that's going on. I want to have a server running using flask and then use curl from another pc to send a file to that server.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  What is needed is the type of file.  Then a post can be made with the correct Content-Type.   You want to use a Content-Type that puts the file in the body of the request.   application/json and text/plain are the easiest.  When its a binary file like image or pdf then  it would likely require base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http.server in the standard library...
https://gist.github.com/mdonkers/63e115cc0c79b4f6b8b3a6b797e485c7

Comment: Just clarifying the above answer. The http.server in the standard library does not by itself handle post data. But you could override it to handle it, such as the example here in github.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I saw that code but I don't know how to edit it to download files from data. Also Nick, could you send a link to the example you're talking about?

Comment: @Niu It is very simple.  All I need to know is the type of file.  Then I can give you the code.  You do not need an external library.

Comment: @Misunderstood Thank you. But isn't there a universal way to upload a file no matter if its an image a document or an executable? Because I would like to upload any type of file to that server.

Comment: The receiving server needs to know the type of transfer.  JSON, TEXT, or BINARY.  The way an email attachment works with a binary file is to encode it using Base 64 so the transfer is 100% text.  Is the Server yours?  Is the PC Windows?  The way I transfer files to a server is to create a Batch file and a Filezilla Pro CLI script.  Then shell out to the CMD line and execute the batch.  The batch file contains  runs Filezilla Pro in a CMD window where the Filezilla script file name is an option on the CMD line.  So you will write the Python script to receive the file?  You can use curl to FTP.

Comment: @Niu Continued from above.  I will start an answer.  But I need some answers.  Especially if you are controlling the transfer on both the PC and the Server.   There is not a "Universal" method.  There are many methods.  FTP/SFTP seems to be the most popular method.  I will suggest some generic curl methods.  I do not use Python so I cannot give you Python code.  Don't miss the above comment.

Comment: @Misunderstood Thanks, to give some more context. The server is mine, I will run the python script on my aws machine. And the pc is windows 10, I would want to just use curl to send the file which is pre installed on windows so that I don't have to install anything or write any scripts. Purly send the file using curl from cmd.

Answer (score 0):

> The server is mine, I will run the python script on my aws machine.
> And the pc is windows 10, I would want to just use curl to send the
> file which is pre installed on windows so that I don't have to install
> anything or write any scripts. Purely send the file using curl from cmd

Sending the file via curl is likely to be problematic.  When I Google curl upload file, I usually find people that have questions that were not answered or advice that does not work.  Without writing a script you easy option is to use FTP. Curl would not be required on the Server.  Either you write a simple script, or use FTP.  The more difficult is on the PC side.  Not all that difficult because you control both sides of the transfer.  
Have you considered using a command line SFTP client?  A secure FTP transfer is very easy using a CMD prompt. One single and simple CMD statement.  
I did a web app for a laboratory.  Every day PDFs with patient lab results are uploaded to a doctor portal.  The docs then go to the portal to view the PDFs. I first wrote this web app 10 years ago.  It has been very trouble free.

I was just beginning my answer, gathering some options when I got you message.
Let me know if FTP is a viable option.  ASAP.  I will get you the command line to FTP a file to the server.

---

---

`pscp` is a free SSH FTP file transfer utility.  I have been using this for over 10 years.  Very reliable.  The date on my pscp.exe, a 316K byte file, is September 2013.

Putty also has another CMD utility `psftp`.  I used it a few times.  `psftp` has a scripting protocol.

Both Putty utilities are very popular and well documented.

This is a sample `pcsp` CMD.  The RUN is the command from my Window app programming language as well.

```
    RUN('CMD /c  ECHO ON & pscp -v -p -pw $password $filename  user@domain.com:server path & EXIT')
```

I went to Fillzilla Pro CLI (command line interface) Even though Filezilla CLI is poorly documented, Filezilla Pro supports transfers to and from These storage services:

```
Amazon S3
Backblaze B2
Box
Dropbox
Google Cloud Storage
Google Drive
Microsoft Azure File Storage Service
Microsoft Azure Blob Storage Service
Microsoft OneDrive
Microsoft OneDrive for Business
Microsoft SharePoint
OpenStack Swift
Rackspace Cloud
WebDAV
```

**I would recommend the free psftp utility from Putty**
The sftp.exe utility is a stand alone 734 KB file. No installation required just copy sftp.exe to any PC where you need it.
If FTP is an option.

[Here is a link to the docs for psftp](https://documentation.help/PuTTY/psftp.html)

These are the FTP commands it supports:

```
6.2.4 The quit command: end your session
6.2.5 The close command: close your connection
6.2.6 The help command: get quick online help
6.2.7 The cd and pwd commands: changing the remote working directory
6.2.8 The lcd and lpwd commands: changing the local working directory
6.2.9 The get command: fetch a file from the server
6.2.10 The put command: send a file to the server
6.2.11 The mget and mput commands: fetch or send multiple files
6.2.12 The reget and reput commands: resuming file transfers
6.2.13 The dir command: list remote files
6.2.14 The chmod command: change permissions on remote files
6.2.15 The del command: delete remote files
6.2.16 The mkdir command: create remote directories
6.2.17 The rmdir command: remove remote directories
6.2.18 The mv command: move and rename remote files
```

---

---

```
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldName"; filename="filename.jpg"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldName"
<input type="file">
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, If it doesn't require installing anything or opening any ports I'm down to use it. I just want a way to upload files from any windows pc without installing anything.

Comment: @Niu Updated my answer.   And the file transfer must be unmanned?